# align* has extra leading vertical space in mdframed

Tags: spacing, align, amsmath, mdframed, vertical

### The problem

Inside an `mdframed` environment, placing `align*` at the **start** of the environment produces extra vertical space above, whereas using `\[\]` instead does not create as much vertical space.  This extra vertical space does *not* appear when `align*` vs. `\[\]` is placed after normal plain text, so the issue is specific to the `align*` + `mdframed` combination.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Outside \texttt{mdframed}, using \verb|\[\]|: \hrulefill
\begin{align*}
  x
\end{align*}

Outside \texttt{mdframed}, using \texttt{align*}: \hrulefill
\[
  x
\]

Inside \texttt{mdframed}, using \verb|\[\]|:
\begin{mdframed}
\[
  x
\]
\end{mdframed}

Inside \texttt{mdframed}, using \texttt{align*}:
\begin{mdframed}
  \begin{align*}
    x
  \end{align*}
\end{mdframed}

\vspace*{3em}

After setting skip lengths to 0:
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}

Outside \texttt{mdframed}, using \verb|\[\]|: \hrulefill
\begin{align*}
  x
\end{align*}

Outside \texttt{mdframed}, using \texttt{align*}: \hrulefill
\[
  x
\]

Inside \texttt{mdframed}, using \verb|\[\]|:
\begin{mdframed}
\[
  x
\]
\end{mdframed}

Inside \texttt{mdframed}, using \texttt{align*}:
\begin{mdframed}
  \begin{align*}
    x
  \end{align*}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

### Possibly related questions

- [mdframed package + align gives extra vertical space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53330/mdframed-package-align-gives-extra-vertical-space)

  This is not a duplicate of that question, since that problem arises from a long `align*` environment getting broken up at a page break, which is not relevant here.

  Notice that the accepted answer for that question, which fixes *that* issue with `\allowdisplaybreaks`, the `align*` environment still produces an unseemly hunk of vertical space above itself when it is placed alone in the `mdframed` environment: [image: unseemly hunk above <code>align*</code>]
- [Align environment creates extra vertical space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202783/align-environment-creates-extra-vertical-space)

  Also not a duplicate, since that issue arises also from page breaks, which are not relevant here.
- [Remove extra vertical space in amsmath's align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172171/remove-extra-vertical-space-in-amsmaths-align-environment)

  Not a duplicate; the issue there arises from placing `align*` in a new paragraph after a hunk of text.
- [Remove vertical space around align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47400/remove-vertical-space-around-align)

  This doesn't address the issue here.  I do not want to blindly remove all vertical space before (and after) `align*` environments, I just want to normalize it with the `\[\]` environment.  Nevertheless, I tried the accepted solution for that question (i.e. `\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}`, `\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}`, `\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}`, `\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}`); this seems to mitigate the issue, but **not** in a desirable way, since I do not want to remove all vertical spacing around my display math environments.

Comment: You also can use  `medframed` with option `[innertopmargin=0pt]` (the default is 5pt).

Comment: +1 for a very good question formatting!

Comment: Related Question: [Excess vertical space in mdframed ending with display math environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44131/4301).

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possibility: prepending the `\setlength{}{}` code at the start of mdframed environments using the `startcode=<code>` key, so that the spaces are only modified in these environments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% 
\mdfdefinestyle{removespace}{%
    startcode = {%
                 \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
                 \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
                }%
}

\begin{document}

Outside \texttt{mdframed}, using \verb|\[\]|: \hrulefill
\begin{align*}
  x
\end{align*}

Outside \texttt{mdframed}, using \texttt{align*}: \hrulefill
\[
  x
\]

Inside \texttt{mdframed}, using \verb|\[\]|:
\begin{mdframed}
\[
  x
\]
\end{mdframed}

Inside \texttt{mdframed}, using \texttt{align*}:
\begin{mdframed}[style=removespace]
  \begin{align*}
    x
  \end{align*}
\end{mdframed}

\vspace*{3em}

After setting skip lengths to 0:
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}

Outside \texttt{mdframed}, using \verb|\[\]|: \hrulefill
\begin{align*}
  x
\end{align*}

Outside \texttt{mdframed}, using \texttt{align*}: \hrulefill
\[
  x
\]

Inside \texttt{mdframed}, using \verb|\[\]|:
\begin{mdframed}
\[
  x
\]
\end{mdframed}

Inside \texttt{mdframed}, using \texttt{align*}:
\begin{mdframed}
  \begin{align*}
    x
  \end{align*}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this user who had been waiting for at least one answer for several days.

Comment: Would this not unintentionally remove spaces in subsequent align* environments _after the first_ one inside an mdframed environment?  Is there a way to only affect the first?