# Using package resizegather leads to extra vertical space inside mdframed equations

Tags: amsmath, mdframed

When I try to add package `resizegather`, extra vertical space is added into mdframed equations. By gradually truncating the code, I found that commenting package `resizegather` would fix the problem. See figure below. But I have no idea, what is behind that. I found similar issues described in tasks:

- [mdframed package + align gives extra vertical space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53330/mdframed-package-align-gives-extra-vertical-space)
- [Extra vertical space inside mdframed theorem environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168642/extra-vertical-space-inside-mdframed-theorem-environment)

but it didn't help

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{resizegather}    
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{My title test 7}
    \blindtext  
    \begin{mdframed}
      \begin{equation}\label{mai:eq1}
        \boxed{\int f(x) dx = F(x) + c}
      \end{equation}
    \end{mdframed}
    \blindtext  
\end{document}
```

[image: using of the package resizegather]

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem with `nccmath` and its `\useshortskip` command:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{resizegather}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{My title test 7}
    \blindtext
    \begin{mdframed}\useshortskip
      \begin{equation}\label{mai:eq1}
        \boxed{\int f(x) dx = F(x) + c}
      \end{equation}
    \end{mdframed}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. Can you explain to me what's going on there?

Comment: I really don't know why mdframed behaves this way. For the vertical  spacing of displayed equations, two kind of rubber lengths can be used: \abovedisplayskip and \abovedisplayshortskip, depending on the length of the last line of text above the equation.  The nccmath command, as you can guess, forces the use of the short version.